# how to construct or initialize an activerecord object in yii2 with arguments?

Tags: activerecord, constructor, yii2, initialization, init

Let's say I want to construct a "player" activerecord object with using some parameters. How can I pass the parameters? Some articles suggest not overriding the __construct method, rather to use the init() function which is supposed to be called internally at the end of the construct method. But how can I pass the parameters to initialize the object? 
If I pass an argument to the constructor it complaints me about:

> Declaration of app\models\Player::init(app\models\Game $game) should
>   be compatible with yii\db\BaseActiveRecord::init()

The code looks like this:

Controller:

```
$game = Game::findOne($id);
$player = new Player($game);
```

Model:

```
public function init(Game $game) {
    $this->game_id = $game->id;
}
```

Comment: You can't pass arguments to `init()` (this method is called internally and it has specified signature), you need to do this in constructor (or by setter).

Comment: Ok I see! Thanks very much! I will rate your answer if you put it into the answer section.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every object which extends `BaseObject` you can initialize your object with the [`$config` parameter in the `__construct()` method.](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-base-baseobject#__construct()-detail)

For example: you can construct your `Player` or `Game` object by passing an array with object property parameters, like `$game = new Game(['player_id' => 1])`.